# CJK spacing suddenly no longer works

Tags: spacing, punctuation, cjk, letterspacing, xecjk

I have been using CJK script in my documents successfully for some time, but today it suddenly stopped working properly. I did update some packages through TeX Live today, and recently I reinstalled a CJK font that I regularly use. However, even when I switch to a CJK font that I haven't touched and that worked fine before—as in the example below—it doesn't compile properly. The problem is the spacing following CJK punctuation marks; the space is either transformed into white boxes with black borders, or come out as XX.XXpt (with X being numerals), depending on the font. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you so much!

Document:

```
\documentclass[utf8,12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[fallback]{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX},Numbers={OldStyle}]{LinLibertineO}
\setCJKmainfont{HanaMinA}
\setCJKfallbackfamilyfont{\CJKrmdefault}{NanumMyeongjo}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt
\usepackage[french,german,american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

Some English, with punctuation.
試試，寫一點中文。可不可以？不性啦。

\end{document}
```

The log includes this:

```
Overfull \hbox (65.9998pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 24--26
\EU1/HanaMinA(0)/m/n/12 ÂØ´ ‰∏Ä Èªû ‰∏≠ Êñá„ÄÇ| minus4.0082pt ÂèØ ‰∏ç ÂèØ ‰ª•Ôº
ü| minus1.58507pt
```

Does that have anything to do with it?

I read through the full log but I didn't see any /error/ messages there, and I think it is too long for me to post here.

I would really appreciate any help I could get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is caused by the `realscripts` package which is loaded by `xltxtra`. There are some following code at the end of the `realscripts` package.

```
% Until these are available in expl3:
%    \begin{macrocode}
\cs_set:Nn \dim_max:nn {
  \dim_compare:nTF {#1>#2} {#1} {#2}
}
\cs_set:Nn \dim_min:nn {
  \dim_compare:nTF {#2>#1} {#1} {#2}
}
%    \end{macrocode}
```

Both `\dim_max:nn` and `\dim_min:nn` had been available in expl3 some times ago. They are redefined by `realscripts` again. But this revision is not appropriate since it dosn't leave neither the calculation result of the maximum or minimum value in the input stream. It undermines our work eventually.

Comment: Is there something lacking at the `expl3` end here?

Comment: No. `expl3` is very fine. This issue is introduced entirely by `realscripts`. `\dim_max:nn` in `realscripts` should be wrapped by `\dim_eval:n` for the correct result.

Comment: @Qing Lee I've tried to put that string of code in the preamble, but it fails to compile. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @QingLee Or actually, I might have misunderstood completely; How do I use this to resolve the issue of spacing when writing in CJK?

Comment: Sorry for the slow action on this; I've now uploaded a new version to CTAN. Should be available shortly.